# How to enable jdbc template in my spring boot test

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, spring-test

I have a cucumber test framework code which is using `@SpringBootTest`, in my test classes i want to configure `JdbcTemplate` to connect to database. I am unable to `autowire` it. If i use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` it looks working but seeing many other errors. Is there a way to enable annotation that i can use to enable jdbc template

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppTestConfiguration.class)
@EnableEncryptableProperties
public class CucumberContextConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.*" })
public class AppTestConfiguration {
}
```

Error i am seeing is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `AppTestConfiguration.java`

Comment: updated by ticket

Comment: In what way have you configured the jdbc template for the non-test scope of your application? Specifically as a bean or through properties set in a `.properties` file?

Answer (score 0):

`JdbcTemplate` can actually be `@Autowired` or `@Inject`ed as it is [documented in the Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-using-jdbc-template).

If this does not work out of the box, check your `pom.xml` for version clashes of the managed dependencies.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration` is not needed manually because it is already contained in `@SpringBootApplication`. Or do you have no Application class itself for example because you have a tests-only artifact?

Comment: As mentioned above its not a spring boot application, its spring boot test. I could make it work by adding `@Import(value = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration .class})` and `@Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }` but seeing hikari pool isValid errors

Answer (score 0):

try to add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` in your test code.

Comment: You cannot use this with JUnit5 - Jupiter